# Centering an icon vertically and horizontally without explicitly defining width?

Tags: html, css

I'm displaying a loading spinner in the middle of my page. Everything works fine and it displays properly and is centered. However, I'm hoping to make my CSS robust enough such that, if the loading spinner style is changed, it still remains centered even with new dimensions.

CSS:

```
body.loading > .fa-spinner {
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    /* TODO: Is it possible to make this not dependent on the size of height/width of the loading symbol? */
    top: calc(50% - 23px);
    left: calc(50% - 24.5px);
    color: #4EA6EA;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body class="loading">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin i-4x"></i>
</body>
```

Where my spinner is currently 49w x 46h

I'm flexible on my display styles as long as font-awesome spinning icon is still supported (I think all display styles are OK.) The CSS only needs to be supported in the latest version of Google Chrome.

Are there any CSS-only options available to me?

Comment: Is your spinner an image (.gif)?

Comment: It is not. It is the font-awesome spinner icon decorated with the font-awesome spin class to induce rotation. http://fontawesome.io/icon/spinner/

Comment: Perhaps this helps http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/gEiDt. By the way, you can't have half of a pixel

Comment: That looks about right. I'll have a read through it and see if I can apply it to my scenario without so much code. I'll edit when I've found a solution.

Comment: Is using a background image an option?  I've had success with a div overlaying image content, although I haven't tried with a full page.